# make the div (in css) to grow bottom-up? how?

Tags: css, html

I'm wondering how to make a div to grow bottom-up and not like it does normally.

I've here a example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEYvk/13/). As u can see the right div will grow with more content but I want both div to stay fixed at the same level. (The left-div will never grow)

How can i make the right-div to grow bottom-up?

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div_1">
        læskdfsædlfksæ
    </div>

    <div id="div_2">  
          <tr>
               <td>AUTHENTIQUE</td>
               <td class="field_2">1.6 16V</td>
               <td class="field_3">239 </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
               <td>AUTHENTIQUE</td>
               <td class="field_2">1.6 16V</td>
               <td class="field_3">239 </td>
          </tr>
    </div>
    <div class="clearing"></div>
    <div id="base"></div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#wrapper{ overflow: hidden;}

#div_1{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

#div_2{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.clearing{ clear: both;}

#base{ border-top: 2px solid #666;}
```

Comment: if u add more content to the table, the div is expanding...

gont get what u mean.

Comment: You HTML is a mess. Don't mix div and tr/td this way

Comment: @yunzen I know I just came up with some quick dirty content to show the idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No luck with float:left, because they are always aligned top. Change to display:inline-block;

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/ZEYvk/15/

Note: No whitespace between `</div>` and `<div ...>`

Answer (score 3):

Changing float to inline is probably what you are after - but you could also absolutely position your div relative to another div it's inside and use `bottom: 0` to keep the div stuck down.

Answer (score 0):

This could be fixed by Javascript.. I used jQuery as shown in the example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/freelancerid/ZEYvk/17/)

I just added the code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#div_1").height($("#wrapper").height());
});
```

Comment: Make sure the jQuery library is included.. it works fine on all browsers.